# Jenkins running build steps on different nodes/slaves

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have master on Linux any slaves on Windows. Jobs building on Windows slaves (I use VirtualBox and JWS on slaves). But there is a problem: anytime virtual machines must to start and to stop when needed project must to build.
So, I want to execute some steps on master (for start and stop VMs) and some one on slaves (building).

Is it possible? And how to use this?

Comment: You could investigate my answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565180/restore-snapshot-before-build-in-jenkins-using-virtualbox-plugin and the original poster fixed it for VirtualBox in the comment

Answer (score 0):

This task can be implemented using several jobs, this is another approach but it is worth to think about it.

1. 1st job starts VM and triggers other jobs (build steps) which you need on another machines
2. The last build step just triggers job which closes VM

I think it is the fastest solution.

Another option can be the next:

1. Job starts VM via a build step
2. Other build steps use SSH connection to Windows machines and run required scripts remotely
3. Build step closes VM